# perform chow test on time series

Tags: linear-model, structural-change, chow-test

I am currently writing on my master thesis, therefore i have to find out if a specific moment had an impact on a time series.
[image]

By just looking at the plot I would say that after the prize reached his maximum at observation 831, there was a shift in the trend... in other words i would say there is a structual break. I wanted to confirm my assumption by performing a chow test

[image]

on the first look i was very happy with the result.

p-value < 2.2e-16

which means that there is a structual break at observation 832

But then i replaced 832 with several different observation numbers and i noticed that the p-value declines if I run the chow test with lower observation numbers.

when i run the test on observation 1 there was a p-value of 0,23

pvalue at observation 200 = 0,19

pvalue at overvation 300 was 0,01

I can perform sctest on every single observation after 300 and it will always show a p-value < 0,01.

what am i doing wrong? is my formula Prize~Trend correct? (I am not that used to R or time series analysis in general)

I am very glad and grateful for your help

Regards

Answer (score 2):

(1) The Chow test is for a change in the coefficients of a regression model at a *known* time. If you don't know at which point in time the (hypothesized) structural change occurs, don't use a Chow test. A natural alternative is to use Andrew's sup$F$ test which formalizes your approach (conducting the Chow test for all possible timings) but appropriately adjusts the corresponding $p$-values. It rejects if the maximum of the $F$ (or Chow) statistics becomes to large. See `vignette("strucchange-intro", package = "strucchange")` for worked examples and more references. Also, `citation("strucchange")` gives you more pointers.

(2) The model `Prize ~ Trend` is surely not appropriate for your data. This would suggest that it is stationary around a deterministic linear trend. Even if you allow for structural breaks and relax it to a piecewise linear trend, you won't find a good model for the `Prize` time series. Probably it would make more sense to model the returns rather than the levels of this time series. But more context would be required for a better recommendation. I suggest you talk to your advisor and ask for more guidance and suitable references.